# How to modify options of a specific Kendo Dropdownlist without affecting other dropdownlist which shares same datasource?

Tags: kendo-ui

I have 3 kendo dropdownlist which shares same datasource. I have a requirement to remove a particular option say the first one (<--Select-->) from one of the dropdownlist, but retain the same for other two. I tried to remove the option using

> $(dropDownListObject).data("kendoDropDownList")dataSource.remove(itemToRemove)

method, but this removed the option from all the dropdownlist. How can I attain this ?

```
Data Source :
-------------------
var data = [
    {Code: "<--Select-->", value:"-1"},
    {Code: "Option 1", value:"1"},
    {Code: "Option 1", value:"2"},
    {Code: "Option 1", value:"3"},
    {Code: "Option 1", value:"4"},
]; 

Snippet where I am trying to remove the option :
-------------------------------------------------------

root.find('.dropdown').each(function (index, item) {
    var dropdown = $(item).data("kendoDropDownList");
    if (dropdown) {
        if ((dropdown.element.attr('removeOption') == "true")) {
            $('#'+dropdown.element.attr('id') + 'option[value="-1"]').each(function () {
                var itemToRemove = $(item).data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.at(0);
                $(item).data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.remove(itemToRemove);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you really have to share the dataSource?  Can't you clone the data instead?

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf : Cloning is what I been thinking about , but couldn't figure out how I could clone the data source residing in a list cache?  I am populating the data to drop down list from a list cache. Can you guide me with steps in cloning the list cached data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since cloning is an option, I would suggested to create 3 distinct `dataSource`.  That way all the data behind will be independent and you won't have to worry about any other data manipulation that could occur in a shared data source (ex: filtering or sorting)

```
var data = [
    {Code: "<--Select-->", value:"-1"},
    {Code: "Option 1", value:"1"},
    {Code: "Option 1", value:"2"},
    {Code: "Option 1", value:"3"},
    {Code: "Option 1", value:"4"},
]; 

var dataClone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, data);

//Create your dataSource with dataClone instead of data
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. This have given me idea to go ahead. I will work on it. Thank you once again.